# How does (A∩B) work in this example?

Tags: probability

**Here is the question statement:**

[image]

**Here is the solution:**

[image]

I'm not sure how we are arriving at **30/180** in P(H∩Hs) since we are supposed to multiply their probabilities, any clues?

Comment: "*since we are supposed to multiply their probabilities*"  It sounds like you are under the mistaken impression that $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.  *This is* **not** *true in general!*  That is true *if and only if* $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  Most of the time $A$ and $B$ will not be independent as is the case here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Hey, since they are not independent in this case, what formula are we using to calculate **Heavy Smoker** AND **Hypertension**?

Comment: $30$ refers to the number of heavy smokers who are also diagnosed with hypertension.  The sum of all numbers in the table, $180$, refers to the total number of people in the survey.  The probability then of a randomly selected person who was surveyed as being a heavy smoker with hypertension is then the ratio of the number of people with that trait divided by the total number of people, i.e. $30$ divided by $180$.

Comment: If you were only wanting the conditional probability, take the number of heavysmokers with hypertension and divide by the number of heavysmokers... in this case $\frac{30}{30+19}$, which you should see gives the same result as doing it the long way (*the division by 180 cancels from top and bottom*).

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh I see, wow okay, this actually makes sense, really appreciate the thorough explanation! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just see how many are heavy smokers and also $H$ (hypertension) at the same time. From the upper right corner of the table, the value is $30$ and we divide it by the total number which is $180$.

If $H$ and heavy smokers are independent, then we multiply them but it is not always true.

Comment: Yes, we want to see how many are **heavy smokers** and also **H** at the same time, but we are dividing by 180 which includes **NH** as well? How does that tell us that the person who is a heavy smoker is also under hypertension? Just doesn't make sense, could you explain it?

Comment: Your universal set include $NH$ as well. That is given this group of $180$ people, $P(H \cap H_s)$ is the probability that when you draw one person randomly, he belongs to the group that is $H \cap H_s$. If you wish, you can compute $P(H |H_s)$ directly as $\frac{30}{30+19}$